# Perl - best practices to diff very large array efficiently

Tags: arrays, perl, key, diff

Seeking advice here. I am a newbie with Perl and looking for input on the quickest way to perform a difference between two arrays.

I am trying to find the differences that are in @arr_1 but are not present in @arr_2.

The two arrays are going to be large, they could be holding between 6,000 to 8,000 elements, these elements will hold unique data and data type is INT in the arrays. Due to the size of these arrays, the diff will need to be fast and not intensive on the CPU.

Here is the code I have used , my question is whether there is a faster way that is less intensive on the CPU?

find the differences

```
    my %diff3;    
    @diff3{ @arr_1 } = @arr_1;
    delete @diff3{  @arr_2};
    @diff = (keys %diff3);
```

Thank you in advance, once I get up to speed on Perl, I am looking forward to paying it back.

Comment: side note; don't have to assign values, `@diff3{ @arr_1 } = ();` also does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two arrays containing approximately 8k unique integer elements, consider using a hash and `grep` to find the elements in `@arr_1` that are not in `@arr_2`.

The module [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) can be used to compare the times for this task using the modules [Set::Scalar](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Set-Scalar-1.26/lib/Set/Scalar.pm), [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.38/lib/List/Compare.pm), your solution, and a hash and `grep`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Set::Scalar;
use List::Compare;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

my @arr_1 = 0 .. 8e3;
my @arr_2 = 2e3 .. 1e4;

sub setScalar {
    my $s1   = Set::Scalar->new(@arr_1);
    my $s2   = Set::Scalar->new(@arr_2);
    my $diff = $s1->difference($s2);
}

sub listCompare {
    my $lc = List::Compare->new( \@arr_1, \@arr_2 );
    my @diff = $lc->get_Lonly;
}

sub OPdiff {
    my %diff3;
    @diff3{@arr_1} = @arr_1;
    delete @diff3{@arr_2};
    my @diff = ( keys %diff3 );
}

sub hash_grep {
    my %arr_2_hash;
    undef @arr_2_hash{@arr_2};
    my @diff = grep !exists $arr_2_hash{$_}, @arr_1;
}

cmpthese(
    -5,
    {
        setScalar   => sub { setScalar() },
        listCompare => sub { listCompare() },
        OPdiff      => sub { OPdiff() },
        hash_grep   => sub { hash_grep() }
    }
);
```

Output:

```
              Rate   setScalar listCompare      OPdiff   hash_grep
setScalar   9.58/s          --        -69%        -98%        -98%
listCompare 31.1/s        225%          --        -92%        -94%
OPdiff       396/s       4034%       1172%          --        -21%
hash_grep    500/s       5119%       1506%         26%          --
```

`Benchmark`'s results are shown from slowest to fastest.  For this diff task, it's evident that using a hash and `grep` is the fastest, at ~1.3x faster than your solution, >15x faster than `List::Compare`, and >51x faster than `Set::Scalar`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears that your expectation is that each array only contains unique elements, it makes sense to use sets. The `Set::Scalar` module can provide this functionality.

```
use Set::Scalar;
$s1 = Set::Scalar->new(@arr_1);
$s2 = Set::Scalar->new(@arr_2);
$diff = $s1->difference($s2);
```

Comment: It's evident from `benchmark`ing (see my Answer) that `Set::Scalar` is not at all efficient for this particular task.  One thing I noticed about the `$diff` object is that it provides access to the  universe of numbers from which the 'diff' is calculated.  Creating and maintaining this 'baggage' may, in part, account for its inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't find the differences, it finds the elements that are in @arr_1 but not @arr_2.  It should be plenty fast with thousands of elements.